# Use quantifiers to express: "There is exactly one person whom everybody loves"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, quantifiers

If $L(x, y)$: “$x$ loves $y$”, the domain consists of all people in the world.

Use quantifiers to express: "There is exactly one person whom everybody loves".

1. $\exists x(\forall y L(y, x) \wedge \forall z(\forall w L(w, z) \implies z = x))$
2. $\exists x \forall y( L(y,x) \wedge  \forall z( L(y,z)  \implies z = x ))$

So, 1 is standard answer, 2 is my answer, is my answer correct?

Comment: i have edited your question. Please verify that I have not changed the content significantly.

Comment: $\exists x\forall z(\forall wL(w,z)\iff z=x)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification

Answer (score 4):

No, (2) is much stronger than (1) because (2) requires that everybody (i.e., $y$) loves only $x$ and nobody else.